generateStaticParams() empty causes error on build. NextJs 15 How does it work?
I'm using this approach on params to be able to export static html files.
The doc say that is correct.
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-static-params#all-paths-at-runtime
But when trying to build (npm run build), the error message is "Error: Page "/products/[id]" is missing "generateStaticParams()" so it cannot be used with "output: export" config."

type Params = Promise<{ id: string }>

const ProductPage = async (props: { params: Params }) => {

    const productId = (await props.params).id

    return (
        <div>
           // content         
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductPage


export async function generateStaticParams() {
    return []
}


I need to use "output: export" to generate static files.
Here is the package.json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev -p 3003",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.13.3",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.13.0",
    "@material-design-icons/font": "^0.14.13",
    "@material-design-icons/svg": "^0.14.13",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.16.7",
    "@mui/material": "^5.16.7",
    "@mui/x-data-grid": "^7.15.0",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.15",
    "axios": "^1.7.6",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.5",
    "material-icons": "^1.13.12",
    "material-symbols": "^0.22.1",
    "next": "^15.0.3",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-markdown": "^9.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.6",
    "remark-gfm": "^4.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.77.8",
    "swagger-ui-react": "^5.17.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/swagger-ui-react": "^4.18.3",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "typescript": "^5"
  }
}




I believe it's because you are trying to generate a dynamic routes page without any product ids. Since, you have used output: export it requires all the dynamic pages to resolve their dynamic slugs or ids on build.
A possible fix can be
export async function generateStaticParams() {
    // it will now know to generate /products/1 page
    // As per docs, leaving this empty will only work for default output build
    return [{id: "1"}]
}


